# How do fflib_SObjectDomain methods implement database transactions (trigger context)?

Tags: apex, trigger, triggercontext, fflib, domain-layer

**How is fflib applying the default values?**

I'm working through the [Apex Enterprise Patterns: Domain & Selector Layers trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_patterns_dsl/apex_patterns_dsl_apply_dl_principles?trailmix_creator_id=strailhead&trailmix_slug=prepare-for-your-salesforce-platform-developer-ii-credential) and I'm confused about how database transactions are implemented from within methods such as `onApplyDefaults()` and `onBeforeUpdate()`.

The module provides this example for how to use `onApplyDefaults()`:

```
public override void onApplyDefaults() {
// Apply defaults to Opportunities
for(Opportunity opportunity : (List<Opportunity>) Records) {
    if(opportunity.DiscountType__c == null) {
        opportunity.DiscountType__c = OpportunitySettings__c.getInstance().DiscountType__c;
    }               
}
```

}

As you can see in this code, there is no DML (nor Unit of Work commit) used to actually "apply the default" data. This code doesn't even alter the `Records` domain class property.

I was able to pass the challenge using the same approach, but I think it's important to know how fflib is actually applying the defaults.

So my question is: How is fflib applying the defaults?

**NOTES:**

1. To clarify, I'm not asking how is `onApplyDefault()` being called. I'm asking how this code is actually making the data in the database change without using DML, a unit of work commit, or updating a super-class property.
2. I won't be providing my challenge code, since this is not allowed by Trailhead/Salesforce, and you shouldn't either.

Answer (score 1):

This method is called on `before insert`, using the parameter `Trigger.new`; any changes you make to those records will be committed after the trigger completes successfully. When you give a method a parameter that is an object, you can manipulate the properties of that object, and the caller will see those changes.